# Combining string and variable in plt.title

Tags: python-3.x

What is wrong in this command?

```
plt.title(r'Step in $e$: ',e_krok,'; step in $q$: ',q_krok,'; $\omega$ = '+str("%0.2f" % i)+' (°)')
```

Error:

```
TypeError: title() takes from 1 to 4 positional arguments but 5 were given
```

When I replace variables ',e_krok,' ',q_krok,' by numbers, it works. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`plt.title` takes 1 string as input, try to format it correctly:

```
'Step in $e$: {}; step in $q$: {}; $\omega$ = {:.2f}(°)'.format(e_krok, q_krok, i)
```

As your error tells you, you are giving 5 arguments to the function (a `tuple` with 5 elements to be exact). See e.g. [here](https://pyformat.info/) a resource on how to use the `.format()` notation.